# how to undo git submodule update

Tags: git, undo, git-submodules

I accidentally checked in a wrong submodule update: ( as part of a bigger commit )

-Subproject commit 025ffc
   +Subproject commit f59250

It is already pushed to the remote..

How do I undo this update?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Run `git checkout 025ffc` in the submodule directory and then `git add SubmoduleName; git commit -m 'Some message'` in the main directory.

(Remember that checking out a commit through its hash leaves you in "detached HEAD state", meaning that you're not on any branch. So if there already is a branch pointing to `025ffc` in the submodule repository, you should check out that branch; otherwise, you'll probably want to create a branch there and check it out.)